# Excel add-in JavaScript - Get the data of the selected cell

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I need to get the data of all the cells in the same row of the selected cell.
Plus, I need to do so every time the user moves to another cell.

So far, I managed to correctly listen to the selection being changed:

```
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function (e) {  
    // Info
});
```

But sadly, the `e` object doesn't contain any data of the column & row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of the selected Cell with the function getSelectedDataAsync. Here is an [example](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getselecteddataasync).

But this function will only return the data of the selected cell.

To get the data of all cells in the row I would do the following steps.

1. You get with your coding in the e object the Binding Id with this Binding Id you can get with the following code the Range of the selection.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var completeBinding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem(<BindingId>);
        var range = completeBinding.getRange();
        range.load('address');
        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            var sSelectedRange = range.address; 
        });
     }).catch(function (error) {
         //Handel error
     });
```

2. Now you have for example the Range F7. Adjust the Range to read the entire row for example to A7:BC7. So basically you only need to know the index of the selected row to generate a Range. With the generated Range you can read your data with the following coding.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sWorksheet).getRange('A7:BC7').load("values");
         return ctx.sync().then(function () {
             var aYourValues = range.values;
         });
    }).catch(function (oError) {
         //Handle Error
    });
```